# Print All the subset from a string

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I want to print all the Ppower set of a string let say the string
INPUT - "ab"
OUTPUT - " ", "a", "b", "ab"

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(string ip, string op)
{
    if (ip.length() == 0)
    {
        cout << op;
        return;
    }
    string op1 = op;
    string op2 = op;
    op2.push_back(ip[0]);
    ip.erase(ip.begin() + 0);
    solve(ip, op1);
    solve(ip, op2);
}

int main()
{
    string ip = "ab";
    string op = "";
    solve(ip, op);
    // cout << "Hello";

    return 0;
}
```

In this code only three subset of this string is coming "a", "b" and "ab" not " ". Dont know where my code is stuck.
Thank you

Comment: It does print the empty string "" . You'll see it if you put an `endl` after `cout` in solve function.

Comment: Your code outputs `baab`. How do you know that "ab" is part of that?  It could be read as "b" followed by "a" then "a" again and "b". How do you know your reading is correct? (Maybe you should put quotes around the string in your output to convince us that your interpretation is correct?)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't get ' ', because your string doesn't contain a space. So therefore it is an exclusion, and when your op is empty then you should print the space ' ', like this see the corrected code. I checked only that part you were wanting for.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(string ip, string op)
{
    if (ip.length() == 0)
    {
        if (op=="") cout << " ";
        else cout << op;
        return;
    }
    string op1 = op;
    string op2 = op;
    op2.push_back(ip[0]);
    ip.erase(ip.begin() + 0);
    solve(ip, op1);
    solve(ip, op2);
}

int main()
{
    string ip = "ab";
    string op = "";
    solve(ip, op);
    // cout << "Hello";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the string contains a space? How do you differentiate the space meaning "empty string" from the space meaning "subset of the string"?

Comment: If this is a case, I think it will be a different problem. Because you said that given a string not a line.
Anyway you can just add additional condition with a flag=[boolean]. If you meet space and flag is false, then flag = true and you print space, otherwise you don't.

Comment: *"Because you said that given a string not a line."* -- First, I did not say anything of the sort. (Did you mistake me for Android Army?) Second, you seem to be confusing terminology. "String" is the general data structure that can contain any character (possibly except nulls) -- spaces in a string are fine. "Line" suggests a string that does not contain a newline character. To suggest a string that does not contain spaces, "word" would be a reasonable choice, although some might want "word" to mean a string consisting of just letters.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I thought you are the author of this post. 
And about string in most problems string referred as a word, like you say. So therefore I counted as he is also doing the same. And in most problems where string contains space, they specify them in statements as line or saying it may contain spaces or smth like this.